# Vue.js prop validation for props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a child component with the following props declaration:

```
   props: {
        count: Number,
        maxNum: Number
   }
```

This is normally fine, but I also have `maxNum` mapped to an input field with:

```
<input type="text" v-model="maxNum" value="maxNum">
```

So even if the user puts "4" in the input, Vue.js thinks that it's a string, when in reality it's a valid number if parsed right.

I tried doing this, but it didn't fail properly on the input "apple":

```
   props: {
        maxNum: {
            validator: function (v) {
                parseInt(v);
                return true;
            }
        }
   }
```

What's the prescribed way of validating props when a v-model is involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, so Vue.JS actually provides a nice way to do this apparently.

```
<input type="text" v-model.number="maxNum" value="maxNum">
```

The `.number` modifier lets the `v-bind:value` part of the `v-model` equation to treat the input value as a number.

Reference on [v-model.number in Vue.JS guide is here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number).

Answer (score 2):

I see you figured out how to solve your issue, but I'll still try to explain what went wrong here.

#### Issue 1

I'm guessing you expected `parseInt` to break on inputs without a number in them, but that's not the case. `parseInt(null)`, `parseInt('foo')` and `parseInt([{ bar: 'Baz' }])` will all work fine, they'll just return `NaN`. Consequently, your validator will always proceed to the second line and return `true`, thus treating any input as valid. To fix it, you would have to run `parseInt` on your input and check if it returns `NaN`, so your validator would like like this:

```
validator: function (v) {
    return !isNan(parseInt(v));
}
```

#### Issue 2

You're not really looking for a validator. A validator just checks input values and decides whether they are valid or not, it doesn't change them in any way. In other words, the corrected validator above wouldn't cast `'13'` to `13`, it would just prevent input like `'apple'` or `undefined`. `'13'` would get through unchanged and you would have to manually cast it later on.

The feature you are looking for was provided as an optional `coerce` function on each component prop in Vue 1, but it was removed for version 2. If you ever need to do it in a slightly more complicated manner that isn't covered by the solution you linked to, the officially recommended way is to [simply use a computed value](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#coerce-Prop-Option-removed).